# Signs of solutions to a quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we have two solutions to a quadratic equation which are
$L_1=-a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ and $L_2=-a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ and the only fact we are given is that $a,b>0$,

**Is it possible to know if $L_1$ and $L_2$ can be of opposite signs if 
$\sqrt{a^2-b^2}>0$?**

We obviously know $L_2$ would be negative but what sign would $L_1$ be?

If we assume $-a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2}>0$ then $\sqrt{a^2-b^2}>a$ then square both sides you get $a^2-b^2>a^2$ so $b^2<0$ which is a contradiction so $-a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2}<0$ right?

But if we at the beginning just took $-a>-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$ and then square both sides, we have $b^2>0$ which contradicts the contradiction, so is it possible to know the bold question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $L_1 L_2=b^2>0$, they cannot have opposite signs.

Answer (score 4):

The product is
$$L_1L_2=a^2-(a^2-b^2)=b^2\ .$$
If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are real then their product is positive and one of them is negative, so the other is also negative.